# How to compile mixed (Java and Groovy) project?

Tags: java, maven, groovy, maven-3

I have a project (Java Swing application), in which I want to mix Java and Groovy.

I can compile and run the project without problems inside IntelliJ Idea.

But I can't compile it with Maven:

1. In `src/main/groovy` I define a Groovy class `GroovyClass`.
2. In `src/main/java` there is a Java class, which uses `GroovyClass`.
3. When compiling the project with Maven, I get the message `[ERROR] ...\JavaClass.java:[13,47] error: cannot find symbol`.

How can I change the `pom.xml` file in order to be able to compile and package the application using Maven?

Comment: my assumption is that the Groovy class cannot be referenced by the Java class.

Comment: @Randyaa incorrect, Groovy classes can call Java classes and vice versa

Comment: interesting. i know they can go the other way... was not aware Java can call groovy classes.

Comment: Actually just thinking about that... It makes total sense that java classes can call groovy classes but compilation order matters since your compilation class path would need to include the groovy classes OR you'd need a compiler that can compile them both. Perhaps this is what IntelliJ does?

Answer (score 0):

Add the groovy-eclipse compiler maven plugin to your pom.xml

Instructions are on the plugins page at https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki/Groovy-Eclipse-Maven-plugin

Comment: Your link is broken, approved replacement it with https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki/Groovy-Eclipse-Maven-plugin sugested edit